# Error encountered while running a PS command to reduce the size of WinSxS folder in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell

I am trying to reduce the size of winSxS by removing some features via Windows PowerShell. I used the following command but it is returning an error message:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Installed -Eq $FALSE} | Uninstall-WindowsFea
ture  -Remove
The term 'Uninstall-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:101
+ Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Installed -Eq $FALSE} | Uninstall-WindowsFeature <<<<   -Remove
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Uninstall-WindowsFeature:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried to solve it by importing the module using this command but it didn't work:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
```

I then tried to run the first command above again but it failed with the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Uninstall-WindowsFeature Uninstalls specified Windows Server roles,
>   role services, and features from a computer that is running Windows
>   Server 2012. By adding the Remove parameter, also deletes feature
>   files, or payload, from a computer. **This cmdlet replaces
>   Remove-WindowsFeature, the cmdlet that was used to uninstall roles,
>   role services, and features in Windows Server 2008 R2.**

Try `Remove-WindowsFeature` instead of `Uninstall-WindowsFeature`

Keep in mind that there is no `-remove` parameter for this cmdlet so your command would be:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object -FilterScript {$.Installed -eq $FALSE} | Remove-WindowsFeature
```

I don't think that this will reduce your WinSxS Folder size. try the [Cleanmgr](https://support.appliedi.net/kb/a110/how-to-enable-the-disk-cleanup-tool-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) tool instead